# Web Logic - cant open installer?

Tags: java, jar, weblogic, java-home

I am trying to install web logic running the following command:

```
java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
```

But when I do I get the following error:

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
    (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\windows\system32>cd C:\Program Files\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1

    C:\Program Files\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
    Launcher log file is C:\Users\608430681\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2018-03-05_
    11-03-53AM\launcher2018-03-05_11-03-53AM.log.
    Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . Done
    This installer must be executed using a Java Development Kit (JDK)
    but C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121 is not a valid JDK Java Home.
    The log is located here: C:\Users\608430681\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2018-03
    -05_11-03-53AM\launcher2018-03-05_11-03-53AM.log.

    Press Enter to exit
```

I have checked my Java home and my path variables and they are valid - what is the issue here?

Comment: Set your `PATH` variable to point to `JDK` instead of `JRE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't like spaces, try to copy your jdk to a non-space path, like:

```
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_152
```

And source files:

```
C:\tmp\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1
```

and if you don't want, you don't have to change your JAVA_HOME, just run:

```
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java -jar C:\tmp\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_Disk1_1of1\fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar
```